# Trying to write something similar to a visual programming language in react without much success (a la puredata, MAX/MSP, unreal engine...)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a modular synthesizer in react. If you don't know what's that don't worry it's not important. It's going to be something similar to some visual programming languages that use modules with inputs and outputs and "cables" (i.e. MAX/MSP, unreal engine, pure data...etc).

I have everything covered except the "cables". I don't know why but this kind of behaviour is quite tricky to implement in react, tried with svg but in the best case scenario it only allows me to draw by clicking on two sockets or (if I add a dragging animation) it just draws a bunch of lines everytime I move my mouse. I'm not going to say that I'm desperate rn but... yeah I'm desperate. Ideally I wanted to add them in such a way that I can customize said cables with bezier curves and make them dodge objects...etc in the future but rn if I can draw a straight line between two sockets I'm happy.

I've already tried svg and konva without much success, I've been struggling with this problem for days and don't know how to solve it.
(Btw, the modules that are connected have onClick events). Ty in advance.

Add a picture for the sake of clarity

[image]

Comment: Check out [LeaderLine](https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/), maybe that will give you some ideas.